# Upload Image to server using base64 encoding android

Tags: android, server, base64

I am trying to upload image string to server but every time I uploaded it gives a message nothing receive from your side (Means empty string).  I also checked the image string after encoding but still I can't upload the string of the image. Could you please help me?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.util.Log;

public class UploadImages {
     String _responseMain;
    private int serverResponseCode;

    public String upLoad2Server(String encode) {


        HttpURLConnection conn = null;


        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;



        try {
             Log.d("encodedImage",  encode);
            URL url = new URL(ConfigImages.UPLOAD_URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);



            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.connect();
            conn.connect();



            OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(encode);

            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            //Read
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            String line = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Uploading............");
                sb.append(line);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
             _responseMain = sb.toString();
            System.out.println("Response of Image Upload : " +_responseMain);


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return _responseMain ;





    }
}
```

Comment: You are just sending the base64 string. But forget to mark it as a parameter or a file. In both cases you should provide a name. What does the receiver expect exactly?

Comment: `Log.d("encodedImage",  encode);`. What does that print?

Comment: `(Means empty string).`. No it means that you did not provide the right identifier/name.

Comment: how I can fix it? I mean how I can send it as file?

Comment: Log.d("encodedImage", encode) will print string of encoded image

Comment: the reciever expect base64 encoded code for image

Comment: the reciever expect base64 encoded code for image

Comment: But how exactly? Under which parametername or filename?

Comment: they don't want any file they just want base64 encoded code for image

Comment: Under which parametername?

Comment: they wrote a php code which they want encoded code send it to that. So i took that url and want to send it to that url. it is kind of API call. http://webexpertsonline.org/dev/turnupapi/v1/and/add_image.php

Comment: this is just I have from their side

Comment: Post the php code here so we can see the code.

Comment: Or post the API here.

Comment: To insert image

API cal :: http://webexpertsonline.org/dev/turnupapi/v1/and/add_image.php

Json format :: {"image_code":"AAARoABQAAAAEAAAEe"}

Response ::
In case of success
{"error": false,"responseCode": 100,"response": "You successfully Insert image code"}
IN case of failure
{"error": true,"responseCode": 101,"response": "You Failed To insert image code"}
 this is just I have from their side it is a API call

Comment: Well if you look at that api you can tell yourself what you are doing wrong i think.

Comment: So what I need to do in this case? How I can fix it?

Comment: is the API wrong or my way for uploading?

Comment: You did not tell yet what you are doing wrong or what you have to do.

Comment: `it gives a message nothing receive from your side`. Sorry but i do not see that text in the API.

Comment: I am trying to send the encoded image which i get from gallery using this API which should receive by their side, I can get the encoded image but when I try to send it they told me we didn't receive anything from your side so I don't know why this encoded string is not throw?

Comment: Yes this message is for previous now they changed it nothing receive from your side at the first it was Failed To insert image code

Comment: You already told that before. I already know that. You better answer my questions concerning the api you posted. You can easily see for yourself that you are not sending the base64string the way they want it. They want `{"image_code":"AAARoABQAAAAEAAAEe"}`. Now first tell what you send instead.

Comment: I already mentioned above how I am sending . I have used the above code to send the string but I am not sure I do in correct way or not.  So please advice me how I can do it?

Comment: You do not have to tell me how you are sending as i can read your code. Just give answer to my question. You dont need code for that. You are not sending the json text `{"image_code":"AAARoABQAAAAEAAAEe"}` but only .... ? Now tell!

Comment: ok bro I solved yes the exact problem was json name thanks I solved I received the accept code right now thanks in advance

Comment: It was really good answer yes the exact problem was JSON name: I send it with another name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending a parameter name like

```
 {"image_code":"AAARoABQAAAAEAAAEe"}
```

Comment: Sorry but that is not in advance. You thanked afterwards like it has to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer :
I have used json format but I didn't specify the name of the json Correctly so the code should be

```
package Uploadvideo;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class UploadImages {
     String _responseMain;
    private int serverResponseCode;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    public String upLoad2Server(String Encode) {


         try {
             Log.d("Vicky", "encodedImage = " + Encode);
              jsonObject = new JSONObject();
             jsonObject.put("image_code", Encode);

             String data = jsonObject.toString();
             String yourURL = "URL Name";
             URL url = new URL(yourURL);
             HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             connection.setDoOutput(true);
             connection.setDoInput(true);
             connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
             connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(data.getBytes().length);
             connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
             OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
             BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
             writer.write(data);
             Log.d("Vicky", "Data to php = " + data);
             writer.flush();
             writer.close();
             out.close();
             connection.connect();

             InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                     in, "UTF-8"));
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             String line = null;
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 sb.append(line);
             }
             in.close();
             String result = sb.toString();
             Log.d("Vicky", "Response from php = " + result);
             //Response = new JSONObject(result);
             connection.disconnect();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.d("Vicky", "Error Encountered");
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return null;




    }
}
```